# Can we use this line sensor as a proximity sensor?

Tags: arduino, mobile-robot, sensors

I have [an RSL Line Sensor](http://www.allsensor.in/ProductDetails.aspx?CID=qcj0eWfX11k%3d&Counter=0&SEOType=BSuwhmB9Ll4%3d&PID=OlyqUUQ3npg%3d&CType=ZgDIC937E8s%3d) which is designed to distinguish black and white lines. It detects white surface and gives me digital *1* as output, with *0* in case of black, but the surface needs to be close to it.

As it uses infra-red-sensors, I wanted to use this sensor as a proximity sensor, to tell me if there is a white surface *near* it. Is it possible to do this?

I think the only problem here is that we need to increase it's range of giving *1*. Currently, it gives *1* only when white surface is too close to the sensors. I want 1 even if the white surface is there at a bit more distance.

Also there is an adjustable screw there to adjust something, under which POT is written. I am working with an Arduino.

Comment: Just out of interest, why do you particularly want to use this sensor as a proximity sensor? You can buy sensors which do what you want, like the [Sharp GP2Y0A21YK](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/242) (and its cheaper).

Comment: i had a competetion and we were given this particular sensor. i was just wondering if i can use this sensor to detect walls at a distance. it's over now!!

Comment: Anyway it's too late: you CAN'T use it in other way that line sensor (it just won't be reliable).

Comment: Does the sensor produce something other than 0 or 1 if the surface is not close enough?

Comment: This is not very good answer. "reliable" needs to be qualified.  I don't see any reason why a 0/1 sensor can't be used this way, assuming sensitivity can be increased as stated. A technical rebuttal or some insights would be a much better way to answer.

Answer (score 2):

This would not be a good idea. As you can see in the specs of your sensor, it has a maximum range of 50mm. It's going to give you lots of faulty outputs if you try to use it for larger distances. My suggestion is to use a line sensor as a line sensor.

Three types of sensors are widely used as proximity sensors:

1. **IR sensors:** Omits IR pulses and receives the reflection. The distance is calculated based on triangulation.

   - *Pros*:

     - Very Affordable.
   - *Cons*:

     - Not a good option for outdoors, because of high IR level in sunlight.
     - It has a noticeable lower range. For example, [GP2Y0D21YK](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/GP2Y0A21YK.pdf) does not see obstacles closer than 10 cm.
2. **Sonar(ultrasonic) sensors:** Sends sound pulses and receives the echo. The distance is calculated based on time of travel.

   - *Pros*:

     - Affordable.
     - Can be used in outdoor environment.
     - More accurate than IR sensor with less noise.
   - *Cons*:

     - Does not work very well with sound absorbing objects.
     - Might see ghost objects, because of receiving response after multiple reflections of the sound wave.
3. **LiDAR (laser range finder):** Sends near IR, visible, or UV light pulses and measures the time of travel. The sensors come in one, two, and three dimensional.

   - *Pros*:

     - Very Accurate.
     - Works with a wide range of surfaces, outdoor or indoor.
   - *Cons*:

     - Not as affordable as the other two.

Answer (score 0):

The sensors which you using as got just an comparator with a variable resistor to adjust the threshold to differentiate black and white line... Sensors with filters can you configured to find the distance from an obstacle which can be used as a proximity sensors .. Anyways proximity sensors are IR based sensors (you can verify using phones camera)...